# Polymer element content not showing up after core-ajax runs

Tags: polymer

I am trying call a polymer page from router.go method of another polymer page.

It reaches the polymer element page and runs the core-ajax that i have defined there.
But after running the core-ajax part it never displays the page i.e. it never displays the content of the page.

page from which i m calling the page not getting loaded ...

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<polymer-element name="create-client" attributes="router" >
  <template>

  <app-router id="router" mode="auto|pushstate|hash">
      <app-route path="/create-project/:clientName" import="/elements/create-project/create-project.html" on-before-data-binding="{{bindToken}}" bindRouter></app-route>

  </app-router>

.
.
.
.<script>
    (function() {
      Polymer('create-client', {
createProject: function() {
          this.$.router.bind('token', this.token, 10);
          this.$.router.go('/create-project/' + this.savedClientName);
        },
bindToken: function(event) {
        debugger;
        // update the route's model before it's bound to the home-page or login-page
        event.detail.model.token = this.token;
      }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Page where it goes and runs the core-ajax but does not reurn the page html.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<polymer-element name="create-project" attributes="clientName router" >
  <template bind "{{clientName}}">  

  <app-router id="router" mode="auto|pushstate|hash">
      <!-- <app-route path="/create-project/:clientName" import="/elements/create-project/create-project.html" on-before-data-binding="{{bindToken}}"></app-route> -->

  </app-router>

.
.
.
<core-ajax
          auto
          url="{{globals.url}}listClients"
          headers='{"Authorization": "{{token}}"}'
          params=''
          handleAs='json'
          on-core-response="{{handleClientsResponse}}">
          </core-ajax>

  </template>

<script>
    (function() {
      Polymer('create-project', {
handleClientsResponse : function(e) {
          this.listClients = e.detail.response;
          console.log(e.detail.response);
        }
```

I could debug and see that core-ajax is run , but my front end never displays the content of this page.

Can anyone let me know what's wrong here?

Comment: Is this project mostly developed already? If not, I'd suggest moving to the 1.0 codebase.

Comment: Yes, its mostly developed. Do you see any issues here that upgrading to 1.0 could solve?

Answer (score 0):

According to Polymer's documentation, you must write the handle-as params in double quotes.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax